EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS swiftui
After reading and trying several solutions like enabling zombie,adding exception breakpoint etc didnt worked for me to find the actual reason of my crash. Below is the stack trace for the crash.
In my application I am having landing page as biometric validation , if user goes in background and comes back from background again biometric validation will happen. so i have used appstate as environment variable.
so when i open the app it shows biometric screen -> success-> dashboard-> background-> network off-> open app -> crash.
if this flow it crashes always where in normal flow it works seamlessly.
    class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    private let networkMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let workerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
    var isConnected = false
    var isNotConnected = false
    
    init() {
        networkMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            self.isNotConnected = path.status == .unsatisfied
            Task {
                await MainActor.run {
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }
        }
        networkMonitor.start(queue: workerQueue)
    }
}

this is the code to check internet connectivity, also in second login option (PIN verification) it works without crash. So I doubt the crash is in biometric class only.
Already invested 2 days in this.looking for your support.
image
enabling zombie,adding exception breakpoint, analysing stack trace of crashlytics
**Please note I also have used environment objects for biometric screen. which are changing based upon app state **

Why do you have both isConnectedand isNotConnected set from the same status?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245501/ios13-check-for-internet-connection-instantly/73595044#73595044

@soundflix i have to provide it to 2 different navigationlink

@loremipsum same issue with above code had already tried that as well

There is something bigger happening then we need an MRE

what is MRE? am i missing anything?

Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

To use async/await in SwiftUI it's .task, e.g. something like this
@State var isConnected = false
@State var isNotConnected = false

...

.task {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    for await path in monitor {
         isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
         isNotConnected = path.status == .unsatisfied
    }
}


Hi, but how to be sure that this is the cause of crash? i am just asking if i am missing anything

as same code works for other verification screen mode in same steps

It's probably because you used Task inside an async closure. To convert closure to async you have to use a continuation. But there is no point since PathMonitor already is async

:0: error: 'makeAsyncIterator()' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
above gives me this error.  target is ios 15.0

Oh in that case use ObservableObject but remove the Task. Change var isConnected to @Published and use DispatchQueue.main to set it within the path handler.

did the changes same thing happening :-(
