Fixing Save Operation When No Network
I have an app that saves transaction data to SwiftData. Recently, I noticed, to my dismay, that I cannot save data when there is no network or internet. After looking at the save operation, it looks like save fails because the app is unable to look up the transaction location. (The getLocation closure in saveButton extends clear past resetting state parameters for the next entry.)
I have been wondering if it is possible to have two save operations: one with network available and another without. The app currently uses the NWPathMonitor extension isConnected when retrieving JSON data, but the problem with using this in saving transaction data is that isConnected is asynchronous while the button logic for the save operation is synchronous. Any ideas on implementing this?
Below are the functions saveButton, getLocation, and an idea for using the path monitor to determine which save operation to complete.
func saveButton() {
    
    withAnimation {
        
        // get coordinates and address
        getLocation { addr in
            self.addr = addr
            
            // address
            if let city = addr.locality {
                entryLocCity = city
            }
            
            if let state = addr.administrativeArea {
                entryLocState = state
            }
            
            if let countryL = addr.countryL {
                entryLocCountryL = countryL
            }
            
            if let countryS = addr.countryS {
                entryLocCountryS = countryS
            }
            
            // entry currency symbol
            let entryCode = currencies.curItem[currencies.entryCur].curCode
            
            // entry money as double (local currency)
            let moneyD = Double(moneyS) ?? 0.0
            
            modelContext.insert(TravelEntries(
                id: UUID(),
                entryDate: entryDT,
                entryMoneyL: moneyD,
                entryLat: entryLat,
                entryLong: entryLong,
                entryLocCity: entryLocCity,
                entryLocState: entryLocState,
                entryLocCountryS: entryLocCountryS,
                entryLocCountryL: entryLocCountryL
            ))
            
            // reset parameters for next entry
            self.entryDT = Date()
            self.entryPT = 0
            self.entryCat = 0
            self.entryDsc = ""
            self.moneyS = ""
        }
      }
   }


func getLocation(completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark) -> Void) {
    
    // get transaction location coordinates from location manager
    let result = lm.getLocationCoordinates()
    entryLat = result.0
    entryLong = result.1
    
    // get location address
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: entryLat, longitude: entryLong)
    location.placemark { placemark, error in
        guard let placemark = placemark else { return }
            
        addr = placemark
        completion(addr ?? placemark)
    }
}
}

Pseudocode proposal for alternate save operation using NWPathMonitor
func saveButton() async  {
        
        // network available?
        if await vm.monitor.isConnected() {
       
            print("Yes, connected to network logic")
            
        } else {
            
            print("No, NOT connected to network logic")
        }
        
    }


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245501/ios13-check-for-internet-connection-instantly/73595044#73595044

The above link isn't any help. It appears that I can use Task {} to call saveButton but not two different functions like what I describe above using isConnected.

The isConnected in the example is nearly identical to the “proposed” solution

I didn’t write an answer because you are mixing old with new concurrency and old/new asynchronous work. But the example is what you are saying you want.

You're mixing things up, and your questions are miles ahead. It's better to look what's wrong directly in front of your code: 1. you should not call an escaping closure in withAnimation. 2. You never need to utilise NWPathMonitor just to execute network requests. 3. You need to understand how to implement asynchronous functions with completions handlers propperly (in getLocation two flaws). 4. Design: you are probably using the reverse geocoding API, which is rate limited and imposes some inherent complexity. So, what you really need  is to come up with a design that is sound.

To find a solution, in this case, it's better to move any async logic into an Observable, which also publishes view state. This might become complex enough, I mean, it becomes interesting ; ). And the view is just rendering state and sending user intents (it performs no logic on behalf of the Observable).
